# I fail to display the value of a select in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, select, geonames

I have a list of countries. I use the GeoNames's function for detect the country where we are and display it in the list. It works.
However, I'd like to retrieve this value, I try to display it but only the first value appears.
Code :

```
<!-- Code HTML countries list -->
<select id="countrySelect" name="country">
<?php
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM pays'); 
echo '<OPTION VALUE="">Pays</OPTION>';
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    { 
    echo '<OPTION VALUE="'.$donnees["id_pays"].'">'.$donnees["pays"].'</OPTION>';
    echo $donnees["pays"];
    } 
?>
```

Code Javascript :

```
function setDefaultCountry() {
 var countrySelect = document.getElementById("countrySelect");
   for (i=0;i< countrySelect.length;i++) {
   if (countrySelect[i].value == geonamesUserIpCountryCode) {
    countrySelect.selectedIndex = i;
    }
     }
   }
/* I want to display the country selected here !!!!!!*/
var c = document.getElementById("countrySelect");
alert(c.options[c.selectedIndex].text);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?
You seem to be building a select...
Do you want to retrieve the value when the user selects something?

Comment: have you verified that indeed something else than the first element was selected? for example with a simple `alert(c.options[c.selectedIndex]);` ?

Comment: you should use jQuery, manipulating DOM through native JavaScript is old

Comment: Abdo Adel: We don't know why he is using native JS, but he is, so why commenting something which doesn't relate to the question?

Comment: @Burki : yes it displays just for the first element of the list

Comment: @AbdoAdel That's terrible advice, and a ridiculous statement. "Native javascript is old", what?! Aside from that silly part of your comment, what if this is literally the only script in the entire project? You suggest he add 10,000 lines of library plus 20-30 lines of code using jquery to do what could be done in 30-40 lines of "native" javascript? Point is, don't add libraries to every project as a knee-jerk reaction. Bad practice.

Comment: @ChrisBaker thx for the advice, but the minimized version of jQuery is not 10,000 lines and there are no 20-30 lines required to use the library it's just 2 lines and 1 line of the element selection, any way you are right about the fact we shouldn't add libraries if the project is small

Comment: @AndersAnderson Well, It's just a suggestion in case that he never heard about jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a little change to your code, for demonstration purposes.

The way to do it is to set an OnChange Event on the Select.
If you then choose an option, it will fire the event.

```js
function setDefaultCountry() {
  var countrySelect = document.getElementById("countrySelect");
  for (i = 0; i < countrySelect.length; i++) {
    if (countrySelect[i].value == geonamesUserIpCountryCode) {
      countrySelect.selectedIndex = i;
    }
  }
  check();
}



function check() {
  var sele = document.getElementById("countrySelect");
  alert(sele[sele.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

```html
<!-- Code HTML countries list -->
<select id="countrySelect" name="country" onchange="check()">

  <OPTION VALUE="Test1">test1</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="Test2">test2</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="Test3">test3</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="Test4">test4</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="Test5">test5</OPTION>
```

EDIT:
just add the following in your body.onload routine:
    setDefaultCountry();

Greetz :)

Comment: Hey, i'm happy for you :D

Please leave an upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: I have a last question about the value selected. I want to have an alert without select an item of the list (a value is already selected initially). How I can have an alert in this case ?